# Handling 'incorrect string values'

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm scraping the text from websites and putting it in a database, but one website's text keeps giving me this error when I try to do the database insertion:

```
Error: ER_TRUNCATED_WRONG_VALUE_FOR_FIELD: Incorrect string value: '\xC2\x80\xC2\x99 s...' for column 'text' at row 1
```

I think this has something to do with character encoding. Is there a function in javascript I can use to simply ignore these incorrect values? It's not critically important that the saved text matches the original perfectly. Alternatively, is there some mysql configuration I can do to support these characters?

Comment: You're probably fighting a non-BMP character; try enabling UTF32.

Comment: Can you share the query and code that generated it?

Comment: The text causing it is fairly long, but here is one character I believe is at fault: …

Comment: Let me add that I think it's at fault because its utf-8 hex value is xE2 which is in the error message for that particular text: '\xE2\x80\x8B\xE2\x80\x8B...'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this by adding 'charset : utf-8' to the mysql connection parameters.

Comment: Had to set `charset: 'UTF8'` in mysql2 knex settings